# Localhost on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: localhost, osx-lion, xampp

I've just obtained a new MacBook Air and am looking to replicate my PC laptop's localhost setup. I'm using XAMPP Lite on the PC to create a WordPress environment.

Anyone know what the options are for setting up localhost on Lion?

When I downloaded the XAMPPLite installer binary, it does not look like its installable (no disk image or installable file to be found, just a few folders)

Answer (score 4):

Use MAMP. (Mac Apache MySQL PHP)

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

Comment: Scott B if you feel this is the answer, go ahead and mark it as such so that people know.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to install using windows setup. you need mac version.
install xampp from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html